# How to avoid generating crc files and SUCCESS files while writing data frame into CSV file?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to save data frame into CSV file using the following code `df.repartition(1).write.csv('path',sep = ',')` then beside the csv file there are other files generated as in the following snippet

[image]

how do I avoid saving the df into CSV file without generating those CSC files? incase there is no possibility how can I let the pandas read the only CSV files out all other files. taking into consideration that there is a file with format csv.crc

Comment: I don't think you can do that. But open to know if it's possible.

Comment: you can use `foreachPartition(f)`, but need to write your own writer which becomes a pure python programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas reading only the csv files you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import listdir

#you can change the suffix, csv will be the default
def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]

your_dir = '/your_path_here/complete_route'

csv_files = ind_csv_filenames(your_dir)

for filename in csv_files: 
  print(pd.read_csv(your_dir+"/"+filename))
```

If you want to read all files in the same dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in csv_files: 
  df = df.append(pd.read_csv(your_dir+"/"+filename), ignore_index=True)
```